# How to map an UnsafePointer to another type?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, optimization

I'm trying to convert an `UnsafePointer<UInt16>` to an `UnsafePointer<Float>` and so far I ended with this solution:

```
let bufferSize = 1024
let buffer: UnsafePointer<UInt16> = ....
let tmp = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buffer, count: bufferSize).map(Float.init)
let converted: UnsafePointer<Float> = UnsafePointer(tmp)
```

It works but I have the feeling it's not an efficient way since I'm creating an intermediate `Array`... Is there a better way to do that ?

Comment: Your code *maps* each UInt16 to a (32-bit) Float. If that is the intention then a new buffer is needed. – Or do you want to *reinterpret* the buffer, e.g. interpret 1024 UInt6 values as 512 Float values?

Comment: @MartinR My intension is to maps each UInt16 to a (32-bit) Float.

Comment: Well, then you *need* a new array, as the floats take twice the space, you cannot just "convert the pointer".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`withMemoryRebound`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafepointer/2430863-withmemoryrebound) to convert a pointer from one type to another:

```
buffer.withMemoryRebound(to: Float.self, capacity: 1024) { converted -> Void in
    // use `converted` here
}
```

But be careful that `MemoryLayout<Float>.size` is `4` (i.e. 32 bits) and `MemoryLayout<UInt16>` is obviously `2` (i.e.. 16 bits), so the `bufferSize` of your `Float` will be half of that of your `UInt16` buffer.

Comment: Thanks I didn't think about that.

Comment: It appears that in my case it doesn't work since the memory rebound is done on the entire buffer, not on each value.

Comment: That is correct. Your question talked about converting pointers, but it now sounds like you want to convert the whole buffer.

Comment: @klefevre - To do that, we'd probably have to know how you wanted to transform that `UInt16` buffer to a `Float`. Perhaps edit your question showing us a few examples of how data would be transformed in this process. Or, even better, give us a broader context of the problem you're trying to solve.